# concatenate text files in multiple folders

Tags: text

I have hundreds of folders with a few text files in each folder.  I'm trying to concatenate the files of each folder into a single text file.  One file for each folder.    Ideally, the concatenated files would be saved to another location.

Answer (score 2):

You can do with a simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

directories="/your/path/dir1 /your/path/dir2 /your/path/dir3"

for d in $directories
do
        cat $(find $d -name "*.txt") > $(echo $d | sed 's/\///g').txt
done
```

This script will concatenate every txt file on `/your/path/dir1` and saves it as `yourpathdir1.txt` in your actual path. Then will do the same with `dir2` and `dir3`.

Comment: Thanks @jherran.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working.  I get the following error"/My/path/file.txt/\: No such file or directory".  Man  wish I know this stuff better,  I feel like you've gotten me really close.